# AngularJs Controller Share

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

i have two controllers in my codes and in one there is an array.I want to use this array from other controller but it does not work.

I have simplified the codes to make them understandable.

My first controller;

```
app.controller('mycont1', ['$scope','$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {

var my;

 my=['1','something',.......];

 }]);
```

My second controller in directive;

```
.....,controller: function($scope) {


   var m=my[0];//i want to reach first controller array..

   }
```

when i call it ,it could not find it.How can i use this array from other controller?

Comment: Share your code properly so that one can understand it..

Comment: i only want to know ,how can i communicate with other controller elements in these types of conditions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular: Share data between controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share data like this between controllers I suggest you create a service that they can both depend on.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <p ng-controller="controller1">{{message}}</p>
    <p ng-controller="controller2">{{message}}</p>    
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []); 

app.service('dataService', function() {
    return {
        message: 'Hello world!'
    };
}).controller('controller1', function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.message = dataService.message;
}).controller('controller2', function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.message = dataService.message;
});
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ben1729/yeLd9rnb/3/

Comment: can you give an example  about it

Answer (score 1):

For small applications. You can use just [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)